# Time complexity of while inside for loop?

Tags: java, loops, time-complexity

I have the following algorithm:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
 String cur = list.get(i);
 int cnt =0;
 while(output.contains(cur)){
  cur= cur.substring(0,5) + String.valueOf(cnt);
  cnt++;
 }
 output.add(cur);
}
```

Not that "list" and "output" are ArrayLists.

I'm thinking that the Time complexity is O(n^2). But what about the while loop that has a output.contains(cur) inside ?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of this algorithm seems to be depending on the initial contents of `output` list:

- `output` is empty, `while` loop is not executed, complexity is `O(N)`, where N is the size of `list`
- `list` and `output` are crafted to comply with `output.contains(cur)` condition
  For example,

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abcde0", "abcde1", "abcde2", "abcde3", "abcde4", "abcde5", "abcde6");
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

The size of `output` will be growing thus the number of iterations will be like this:

```
1) n+1
2) n+1 + n+2 = 2 (n+1) + 1
3) n+1 + n+2 + n+3 = 3 (n+1) + 3
4) n+1 + n+2 + n+3 + n+4 = 4 (n+1) + 6
...
n) n (n+1) + (1 + n-1)*(n-1)/2 = n (n+1) + n (n - 1)/2 = n (3n + 1)/2
```

Thus, in this (possibly not the worst case) the complexity can be O(N^2).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the answer! Should I count that the contains() method takes O(n)? Or only the iterations matter?

Comment: Right, I completely overlooked that linear search wirthin a list takes place.